# mySQL join same table twice

Tags: mysql

I'm trying this:

```
select 
audit_log_entries.created_at,
audit_log_orig_term_types.name as originator,
audit_log_orig_term_types.name as terminator
from audit_log_entries 
join audit_log_orig_term_types on audit_log_entries.originator_type_id = audit_log_orig_term_types.id
join audit_log_orig_term_types on audit_log_entries.terminator_type_id = audit_log_orig_term_types.id;
```

I think the intent is clear, I want both names for the originator and terminator. I have their IDs in the first table and the names on the other table.

I am getting an error from this: `ERROR 1066 (42000): Not unique table/alias: 'audit_log_orig_term_types'`

where's the mistake in the syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make like this :

```
select 
 audit_log_entries.created_at,
 audit1.name as originator,
 audit2.name as terminator
from audit_log_entries 
 join audit_log_orig_term_types audit1 on audit_log_entries.originator_type_id = audit1.id
 join audit_log_orig_term_types audit2 on audit_log_entries.terminator_type_id = audit2.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to alias the tables:

```
join audit_log_orig_term_types AS alias1 on audit_log_entries.originator_type_id = alias1.id
                               ^^^^^^^^^                                           ^^^^^^
join audit_log_orig_term_types AS alias2 on  audit_log_entries.terminator_type_id = alias2.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an alias for the joined tables:

```
Join table1 as t1 on t1.Id = [...]
```